# Правильное написание тэга php

Tags: теги, php

пишу всегда вот так:

```
<? some code ?>
```

Часто вижу так:

```
<?php  some code ?>
```

даже в современных скриптах.

В чем дело? Или на сегодняшний день это не имеет значение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имеет значение, если в настройках php включены `short tags`, то это `<? some code ?>` будет работать, иначе нет. Подробнее: [`short_open_tag boolean`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Comment: это зависит от настроек на сервере хостинга, не так ли?

Comment: @Deus, да. Но эту настройку вы можете включать/выключать в .htaccess. Лучше всего использовать <?php ?>, так как будет полная совместимость со всеми хостингами и не будет проблем. Короткую форму записи я сам не использую и вам не рекомендую

Answer (score 0):

Мне гуру всегда говорили, что надо писать **`<?php ?>`** - это правило хорошего тона. Да еще и IDE у меня частенько ругается, если напишу **`<? ?>`**.

И в последних версиях для удобства вместо **`<?php echo $retStr; ?>`** пишу **`<?=$retStr;?>`**

Comment: <?=$retStr?>

 - `;` не нужна. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php

Comment: мне больше нравится с ; - визуально отделяет

Comment: Еще более желательно писать просто: <?php

т.е не закрывать тег php, если это возможно.

Comment: @shurik, ну да )

а что вы скажите на счет добавления в конце всей странички строчку на javascript дающую ошибку?

Comment: @IVsevolod, просто нужно контролировать футер страницы, чтобы там все было ок, а во всех подключаемых скриптах, классах и модулях НЕ РЕКОМЕНДУЕТСЯ ставить завершающий тэг '?>'